# Web3 EIP 1599 transaction

Tags: web3js, rinkeby, eip-1559

I am trying to swap a coin using the uniswap router on rinkeby with a EIP 1599 transaction.  Here is the important part of the code:

```
        "data": data.encodeABI(),
        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x01",
        "maxFeePerGas": "0xff",
        "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(count + txNum),
        "to": uniRouterAddress,
        "value": web3.utils.toHex(amountToBuyWith),
        "chainId": "0x04",
        "accessList": [],
        "type": "0x02"
      }

    const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData(txData, { common })
    
    const signedTx =  tx.sign(privateKey);
    const serializedTx = '0x' +  signedTx.serialize().toString('hex');
    try {
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx).on('transactionHash', function(hash){
            console.log(hash);
        })
        .on('receipt', function(receipt){
            console.log(receipt);
        })
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ 
            console.log(confirmationNumber); 
        })
        .on('error', console.error); // If a out of gas error, the second parameter is the receipt.
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('EXCEPTION: ' + ex);
        console.trace();
    }
```

When I do this, the transaction will show up in etherscan for a short period of time then disappears, and the transaction is never confirmed.  Has anyone ever seen this where the transaction lands on etherscan for just a few moments?